# what is the iOS equivalence of Android RelativeLayout/LinearLayout?

Tags: android, ios, android-layout, android-relativelayout

How do I control the relative position of views, especially I wish my app to run on 3.5 inch display and 4 inch display seamlessly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7072966/relativelayout-or-linearlayout-in-ios-iphone-development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this: [iOS 6 apps - how to deal with iPhone 5 screen size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396545/ios-6-apps-how-to-deal-with-iphone-5-screen-size) and [How to add iPhone 5 large screen support to iOS apps in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396143/how-to-add-iphone-5-large-screen-support-to-ios-apps-in-xcode)

But it's done for you for the most part with auto layout. Click on your project in Xcode and go to the Summary tab to add the different screen size launch screen for your app.

Answer (score 4):

As of iOS 9 you can use `UIStackView`, which works very similarly to `LinearLayout`: you add views and the stack view arranges them as needed based on your sizing option – if you're using Interface Builder you can experiment with each of the options to see which one suits your needs. You can also set spacing between views in the stack view, adding some padding.

**WARNING**: When adding stack view child views in code you should always use `addArrangedSubview()` like this:

```
stackView.addArrangedSubview(someView)
```

If you try to use plain old `addSubview()` it won't work correctly, because the stack view won't know to arrange it.

As for removing, you need to be careful to use `stackView.removeArrangedSubview(someView)` *and* `someView.removeFromSuperview()` otherwise the view won't be removed correctly.

You might find my [UIStackView tutorial](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/31/overview) useful.

Answer (score 2):

There is no equivalent or relative and linear layouts. The UI elements have autoresizing masks which define how will they be moved/stretched when their superview is resized (e.g. screen rotation). You can also use layout constraints for positioning if you intend to build your app for iOS 6+. If you can't solve the repositioning using these tools, you should change the frames of the UI elements in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Auto-Layout system ≫ RelativeLayout

UIStackView ≈ LinearLayout

IMO. UIStackView was not well designed

1. can't easily add extra constraints between subviews/subview and superview
2. it's too often to produce conflicts of constraints

   x. iOS 9+ only

So i wrote AutoLinearLayoutView, a replacement of UIStackView.

[Demo screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9RQ8.gif)

Checkout from Github [AutoLinearLayoutView](https://github.com/qianbin/AutoLinearLayoutView)